# Swiftui - unable to access environment object

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui, network-programming

Im working on a project were I make a network call to a server and get different data back depending on the type of call I make. The issue I am facing is access the variables from my data that is decoded into a struct to display on my views. The struct starts out as nil at first but decodes when the user signs in before presenting the content view. My json is able to decode without any issues. If anyone has any suggestions on how I can optimize my code to work, that would be much appreciated. im new to swift so this is all a learning experience for me

This is some of my network code

```
struct NetworkService {
   
    static let shared = NetworkService()
    
    // Singleton that Only allows one instance of this class 
    private init() {}
    
    func request<T: Decodable>(endPoint: EndPoint, method: Method, parameters: [String: Any]? = nil, completion: @escaping(Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
        // Creates a urlRequest
        guard let request = createRequest(endPoint: endPoint, method: method, parameters: parameters) else {
            completion(.failure(AppError.invalidUrl))
            return
        }
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        
        session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            var results: Result<Data, Error>?
            
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                completion(.failure(AppError.badStatusCode))
                return
            }
            
            if let response = response {
                /*
                // Gets the JSESSIONID - Remove?
                let cookieName = "JSESSIONID"
                if let cookie = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies?.first(where: { $0.name == cookieName })  {
                    debugPrint("\(cookieName): \(cookie.value)")
                }*/
               
                print(response)
            }
            
            if let data = data {
                results = .success(data)
                
                
            } else if let error = error {
                results = .failure(error)
                print("Server Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.handleResponse(result: results, completion: completion)
            }
            
        }.resume()
    }
    
    
    /// Helper function that decodes JSON data response from server
    private func handleResponse<T: Decodable>(result: Result<Data, Error>?, completion: (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
        guard let result = result else {
            completion(.failure(AppError.unknownError))
            return
        }
        
        switch result {
        
            case .success(let data):
                
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                    print("Server JsonObject response: \(json)")
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(AppError.errorDecoding))
                }
                
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                // Decodes that json data
                do {
                    let json = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
                    completion(.success(json))
                    
                } catch {
                    print("This caused the problem")
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
                
                
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))
        }
        
    }
```

This is my AuthViewModel that as a source of truth for decoding my json data

```
class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var user: LoginResponseData.Root? = nil
    @Published var alert: CustomAlert? = nil
    @Published var claimHistroy: ClaimStruct? = nil
    
    var authentication: AuthenticationCheck? = nil
    
    var showLoader = false
    
    let networkService: NetworkService = NetworkService.shared
    
    func signIn(username: String, password: String) {
        networkService.signIn(username: username, password: password) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let user):
                print("This user last name is: \(user.result.login.userName.name.fullName)")
                self.user = user
                 
                self.authentication?.updateValidation(success: true)
                
                // Calls method
                self.profileSessionMember()
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print("The error is: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                //Reset the variable
                //self.user = nil
                self.authentication?.updateValidation(success: false)
                // Pass a message to the user 
                self.alert = CustomAlert(title: "Invalid Credentials", message: "Either username or password is incorrect. Please try again")
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// Gets the Search Savings Amouny from decoded struct
    func profileSessionMember() {
        networkService.profileSessionMember { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let userHistory):
                // Sets the claimHistory
                self.claimHistroy = userHistory
                print("This happened")
                print(self.claimHistroy?.result.member.yearToDateSearchSavingsAmount ?? "didnt work")
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    func logout() {
        self.user = nil
        authentication?.updateValidation(success: false)
    }
    
    
    //This assists in creating a shared alert
    struct CustomAlert : Identifiable {
        let id: UUID = UUID()
        var title: String
        var message: String
    }
    
    
    
} // End of AuthViewModel


class AuthenticationCheck: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isValidated = false
    
    func updateValidation(success: Bool) {
        withAnimation {
            isValidated = success
        }
    }
}
```

This is some of my content view that passes the object to the environemt

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var test: AuthViewModel = AuthViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView {
           Home()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                    Text("Home")
                }
         
            Search()
                .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    Text("Search")
                }
            
            Text("Profile Page")
                .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                    Text("Profile")
                }
        }//tab view ends here
        .environmentObject(test)
```

This code that does not work and still shows up as nill is commented below

```
struct SearchHistory: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("BASED ON YOUR SEARCH HISTORY")
                .font(.title3)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.584, green: 0.655, blue: 0.992, opacity: 100.0))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding()
            
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "dollarsign.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 43.0, height: 44.0)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .padding()
                
                VStack{
                    Text("Total")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    Text("Amount")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    // Display Search Saving
                    // This shows up as nil
                    Text(String(describing: vm.claimHistroy?.result.member.yearToDateSearchSavingsAmount))
```

This is where my sign-in is called

```
struct SignIn: View {
    @StateObject var vm: AuthViewModel = AuthViewModel()
    @EnvironmentObject var authentication: AuthenticationCheck
    @Binding var userID: String
    @Binding var passcode: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            // Remove
            print("Button action")
            vm.signIn(username: userID, password: passcode)
            
        }) {
            Text("Sign In")
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding()
        }
        .frame(width: 150.0, height: 43.0)
```

Comment: from where SearchHistory is opened? can you share the code where it is opened?

Comment: for "claimHistroy" (probably misspelled) to have some data in it, you must call a successful "signIn(...)" before 
you use it. There is no call to "signIn(...)" in your ContentView. 
Where do you call "signIn(...)? Is it in Home and does it happens before you use "claimHistroy"?

Comment: @workingdog I call it in my sign-in view. I edited my code and added it

Comment: @workingdog content view doesn't call my signin view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in SignIn you have a AuthViewModel and in ContentView you have another AuthViewModel. This is why you are not getting the data in claimHistroy. These are two separate models. Restructure your code to use only one AuthViewModel, and pass it where you need it. In other words use:

```
@StateObject var vm: AuthViewModel = AuthViewModel()
```

before SignIn and ContentView.

Comment: Omg Thank you. I don't know why I didn't catch that at first bc my AuthViewModel is a class not a struct.